# Detectar agujeros en una silueta usando OpenCV y Python

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy tratando de detectar los agujeros dejados en una silueta de tiro usan HoughCircle. He intentado ajustar los parámetros pero no consigo detectar del todo bien.

Esta es la silueta original:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es aplicando los algoritmos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('silhouette.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret0,thresh0 = cv2.threshold(imgray,180,200,cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh0,40,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(7,7),0)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(mask,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,6,
                    param1=50,param2=8,minRadius=1,maxRadius=13)

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(imgray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) 

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(imgray,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center imof the circle
    cv2.circle(imgray,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),2)


cv2.imshow('detecion', imgray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Alguna idea para mejorar la detección de los agujeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una aproximación totalmente diferente, que si pudieras implementarla tal vez sea  más efectiva, es analizar diferencias. La idea es, partir de una silueta "limpia", idealmente sería una imagen previa a haberse efectuado los disparos (o al menos una foto con la silueta) y la imagen posterior ya con los huecos. El éxito de esta estrategia, claro,  depende que ambas siluetas varíen lo menos posible (salvo los disparos).

Adapté a tu caso este excelente tutorial: [Image Difference with OpenCV and Python](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/)

Partimos de dos imágenes, un antes y un después, una imagen "limpia" y una con los disparos. Obviamente, en este caso la imagen limpia es "ideal" por que es la original a la que le hemos eliminado los disparos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para empezar vas a necesitar instalar dos paquetes adicionales:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-image
pip install --upgrade imutils
```

Lo siguiente, leemos las dos imagenes y las llevamos a una escala de grises:

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2

clean = cv2.imread('clean.jpg')
post = cv2.imread('pro.jpg')

cleanG = cv2.cvtColor(clean, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
postG = cv2.cvtColor(post, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Ahora comparamos las diferencias mediante  [`compare_ssim()`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.compare_ssim) o Structural Similarity Index (SSIM), que además de darnos un `score` (índice de similitud) no retorna un array que representa una imagen con las diferencias.

```
(score, diff) = compare_ssim(cleanG, postG, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego simplemente hay que detectar los contornos sobre la diferencia entre ambas imágenes y agregarlos a la imagen original:

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(clean, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(post, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("Modified", post)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No había tomado en cuenta este enfoque distinto de resolver el problema, interesante. En la vida real creo que los mismos impactos de bala podrían mover la silueta, tal vez por ahí me aparezcan más diferencias aparte de las balas mismas. Será cosa de hacer pruebas.

Comment: @RicharFernandezVilchez, es cierto, la silueta puede variar de ubicación bastante. El problema es que los patrones de los disparos son bastante ambiguos, por lo que hay que buscar cualquier forma posible para destacarlos. Tal vez una captura en color, si además pudieras manejar una iluminación desde atrás con un color que no existiera en la foto, sería bastante más sencillo.

Comment: Claro es verdad, filtrarlo por color sería más fácil. Tu aporte es muy bueno, gracias por compartir tus conocimientos @PatricioMoracho